# Angular 5 window scroll event fired few times

Tags: angular, events, scroll, window

I'm noticing that in my Angular project when I try to listen for a window scroll event my function get executed 1 time per scroll, at the end of the scroll action. At most my function get called twice: when the scroll start and when the scroll ends.

While if you look at this plunker, where I used Jquery, it logs more then 10 times for a single scroll action :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());

});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/z3Ajg1fg05OXKRkHMca0?p=preview

The problem now is that I tried to reproduce the error that I have but I couldn't. 
Indeed if you look at this fiddle made with angular it works like jquery.
https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/6592/

The code that I have is the same:

```
constructor() {
window.onscroll = (s) => {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    };
}
```

And It logs just 1 or 2 times per scroll action in my project. Do you have any Idea why this is happening? Please help

I have tried all the others method like:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
```

or:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    scrollHandler(event) {
      console.debug("Scroll Event");
    }
```

Comment: In my project, when I scroll with the mouse for a single scroll action, it scrolls 100 pixel  and calls my function just once, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular DOM Manipulation you should not use java script. angular framework is mainly created for manipulating dom in angular way.

`window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);` is not intended way to listen event in angular

You can use window:scroll to detect the scroll event. i have created custom directive for handle the scroll check this example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/bottom-ovzmcq

Comment: same thing, if I use this @HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll(event){
    console.log('1');} it logs just once per scroll action

Comment: check my example i have added window:scroll it is working fine